# how to open description p tag on finding text match with search box otherwise p tag should be disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to create a search content which has a search box, a heading and a paragraph description. By default description is disabled and when i enter some text which matches with description text then description paragraph tag should open.  Some matching demo is like this :

[fiddle][1]

but in this by default p tag should be disabled and would be visible only when the search text is matched.

```js
function highlightSearch() {
    var text = document.getElementById("query").value;
    var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
    var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
    var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
    document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = enew;
    var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>");
    document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = newe;
 
}
```

```css
#searchtext span{
    background-color:#FF9;
    color:#555;
}

div {
    padding: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div><h2>Find and highlight text in document</h2>
<form action="" method="" id="search" name="search">
<input name="query" id="query" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30">
<input name="searchit" type="button" value="Search" onClick="highlightSearch()">
</form></div>
<div id="searchtext">
<p>JavaScript is the programming language of the Web. The overwhelming majority of
modern websites use JavaScript, and all modern web browsers—on desktops, game
consoles, tablets, and smart phones—include JavaScript interpreters, making Java-
Script the most ubiquitous programming language in history. JavaScript is part of the
triad of technologies that all Web developers must learn: HTML to specify the content
of web pages, CSS to specify the presentation of web pages, and JavaScript to specify
the behavior of web pages. This book will help you master the language.</p>
  
<p>If you are already familiar with other programming languages, it may help you to know
that JavaScript is a high-level, dynamic, untyped interpreted programming language
that is well-suited to object-oriented and functional programming styles. JavaScript
derives its syntax from Java, its first-class functions from Scheme, and its prototypebased
inheritance from Self. But you do not need to know any of those languages, or
be familiar with those terms, to use this book and learn JavaScript.</p>
  
<p>The name "JavaScript" is actually somewhat misleading. 
  <span>Except</span> 
  for a superficial syntactic
resemblance, JavaScript is completely different from the Java programming language.
And JavaScript has long since outgrown its scripting-language roots to become
a robust and efficient general-purpose language. The latest version of the language (see
the sidebar) defines new features for serious large-scale software development.</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Your fiddle is missing the link.

Comment: I agree, the translation is a little off, making it hard to understand. Try to improve on the English so we can help you.

Comment: Could you be more elaborative and accurate with your question.

Comment: Please try below given solution with updated JS and CSS, I hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below JS -

```js
  
function highlightSearch() {
        var text = document.getElementById("query").value;
 
         if ($("#searchtext").has(":contains("+text+")").length) { 
           $('#searchtext').show();
          }
        else 
           {
             $('#searchtext').hide();
            }
      var query = new RegExp("(\\b" + text + "\\b)", "gim");
        var e = document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML;
        var enew = e.replace(/(<span>|<\/span>)/igm, "");
        document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = enew;
        var newe = enew.replace(query, "<span>$1</span>");
        document.getElementById("searchtext").innerHTML = newe;
     
    }
```

```css
#searchtext span{
        background-color:#FF9;
        color:#555;
    }

    div {
        padding: 10px; 
    }
#searchtext {
display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: helo all u i am new here so facing some proble to post question next time will be fine every thing